# How to add the custom components in AEM?

Tags: aem, aem-6, aem-core-wcm-components, aem-project-archetype, aem-developer-tools

How to do the custom components in AEM?
like i have tried to do it by changing the html code in clientlibb but do not understand how to do it properly

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom component you need to create a component node under `/apps/<your_proj>/component`. Once created, under the node rename the .jsp file to .html and then add your dialog node.
This [link](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/getting-started-wknd-tutorial-develop/project-archetype/custom-component.html?lang=en) should help.